# Keycloak: is it possible to script groups in config json file?

Tags: json, config, keycloak

I can configure keycloak user in my users.json file:

```
{
  "realm" : "my_realm",
  "users" : [ {
    "id" : "my_id",
    "createdTimestamp" : 1568195319743,
    "username" : "my_user_name",
    "enabled" : true,
    "totp" : false,
    "emailVerified" : false,
    "credentials" : [ {
      "type" : "password",
      "hashedSaltedValue" : "XXXXX",
      "salt" : "XXXXX",
      "hashIterations" : 27500,
      "counter" : 0,
      "algorithm" : "pbkdf2-sha256",
      "digits" : 0,
      "period" : 0,
      "createdDate" : 1568195377551,
      "config" : { }
    } ],
    "disableableCredentialTypes" : [ "password" ],
    "requiredActions" : [ ],
    "realmRoles" : [ "offline_access", "uma_authorization" ],
    "clientRoles" : {
      "account" : [ "manage-account", "view-profile" ]
    },
    "notBefore" : 0,
    "groups" : [ ]
  }]
}
```

When I start the keycloak container, those get loaded into keycloak database.

Can I script **user groups** the same way (in this file or some other file)?
And map the users to the groups?

Comment: You can configure Keycloak according to your requirements using its user interface, then do the configuration export (Menu -> Manage -> Export), and you'll have full JSON file as an example of configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it's simple (but also not documented):

```
{
  "realm" : "my_realm",  
......................
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": "<my group id>",
      "name": "<my_group_name>",
      "path": "/<my_group_name>",
      "attributes": {},
      "realmRoles": [],
      "clientRoles": {},
      "subGroups": []
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

I figured this out by creating groups in keycloak admin interface, clicking "Export" and reading the downloaded file.